# SQL help on self Join query

Tags: sql

Two tables customers table and payment table

Payment table

```
paymentid int
paymentdate date 
custid int
```

Customers table

```
Custid int 
name varachar
paymentcustid int
```

foreign key constraints:

1. `payment.custid` refers to `customer.custid`
2. `payment.paymentcustid` also refers to `customer.custid`

Write a query to fetch the name of the `paymentid`, `paymentdate`, name of the `customer`, name of the `payment customer`.

Table structure would be like

Payment table

```
paymentid paymentdate  custid 
100         07/11/18     1
101         08/11/18     3
102         08/11/18     4
```

Customer table

```
Custid name paymentcustid
1       a       4
2       b       3
3       c       5
4       d       5
5       e       1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Also, tag your DBMS.

Comment: Probably a good idea to read [how to ask a homework question on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). They are allowed here, but there's some guidelines that should be followed like *"Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first"* and *"Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation."* for instance. As it stands this reads like it was copy and pasted from a test/quiz/worksheet and we are to answer it for you wholesale. Tedious for us, and probably not very helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need :

```
SELECT
    p.paymentid,
    p.paymentdate,
    c1.name payment_customer,
    c2.name customer
FROM 
    payment p
    INNER JOIN customers c1 ON p.cust_id = c1.paymentcustid
    INNER JOIN customers c2 ON p.cust_id = c2.custid;
```